# ManyToMany category field -- Display title instead of id in django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

ManyToMany category field -- Display title instead of id in django restframework

Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,null=False, unique=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BlogPostModel(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='catitems')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,null=False, unique=True)
    background_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post-images',blank=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='post-images',blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='post-images',blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want display category's title instead of category's id

Serializer

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.CharField(source='author.email', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
            model = BlogPostModel
            fields = ['author','category','title','body','slug','background_image','created_date']
```

This is the result of my codes:

```
        "category": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
```

And i want this:

```
        "category": [
             Category title(1)،
             Category title(2)،
             Category title(3)
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate serializer for category like this:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
   class Meta:
      model = CategoryModel
```

Now you can include the category serializer in PostSerializer like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True)
    ...
```

Also don't forget to do `prefetch_related` to improve the performance wherever you are calling the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize SlugRelatedField() for this:
You can make the following changes to your Serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='title', queryset=Category.objects.all())
    author = serializers.CharField(source='author.email', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
            model = BlogPostModel
            fields = ['author','category','title','body','slug','background_image','created_date']
```

Documentation of DRF [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for reference